# Python one special character in password

Tags: python, passwords

I have a tiny problem, because i want to check user password and force so that must using one special character. But in my output i get a invalid message even though password is created. How can i repair this thing?

```
special_character= '$#!'


created = False
while not created:
    password = input('Type your password: ')
    for char in special_character:
        if char in password:
            print('Password Created!!')
            created = True
    else:
        print('Sorry, try again!')

Output:
Type your password: MyStronPassword123$
Password Created!!
Sorry, try again!
```

How can i discard this text: "Sorry try: again"

Comment: It works fine if you change `else` to `if not created`, but I recommend you to use regex (regular expressions).

Comment: After created = True, put `break`

Comment: Note you're using the unusual for-else construct rather than if-else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an if statement to see if the password is created.

```
special_character= '$#!'

created = False
while not created:
    password = input('Type your password: ')
    for char in special_character:
        if char in password:
            print('Password Created!!')
            created = True
    if not created:
        print('Sorry, try again!')
```

Output:

Type your password: MyStronPassword123$

Password Created!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following method:

```py
sc = '$#!'
ps = "test!"
for i in sc:
    if i in ps:
        print("GOOD")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` statement will always be executed, I suppose you want it to be executed only if the for loop is interrupted in that case add `break` :

```
special_character= '$#!'


created = False
while not created:
    password = input('Type your password: ')
    for char in special_character:
        if char in password:
            print('Password Created!!')
            created = True
            break
    
    else:
        print('Sorry, try again!')
```